# Remove all occurrences of a value from a list in linear time

Tags: python, algorithm, big-o

I would like to implement a program in python where all occurrences of a value are removed from a list in place and in linear time (O(n)). There have been posts of problems similar to this, but none had the constraint of doing it in linear time.

I managed to come up with a solution, but I am looking for a more simpler and cleaner version (or preferably a totally different implementation).

Below I use two "pointers", back and front, to traverse through the list. Both start at 0 and go through the list until they hit the value that want we want remove. At that point the front pointer checks if the integers after are also the values we want to remove. Front pointer continues to traverse until we hit the first integer, which is not the value we want. Then I swap value and continue the process.

```
def remove_all(lst, val):
    back = 0
    front = 0
    while (front < len(lst)-1):
        while(front < len(lst) and lst[front] != val):
            front += 1
            back += 1
        if (front < len(lst)-1 and lst[front] == val):
            while(front < len(lst)-1 and lst[front] == val):
                front += 1
            lst[back], lst[front] = lst[front], lst[back]
            back += 1
    if (lst[-1] != val):
        raise ValueError('Value not present in the list')
    while(len(lst) != 0 and lst[-1] == val):
        lst.pop()
```

Comment: Is this a linked list?

Comment: No, a regular array.

Comment: Then what's wrong with `[x for x in lst if x != val]`?

Comment: That creates a new list (array), which would not be in place.

Comment: @MadhavNakar That really doesn't matter if you store the new list with the same variable. Whenever your python interpreter feel like, it'll clean the space used by your older list

Comment: My assignment mentions to not create a new list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you would use a list comprehension, a generator expression or the `filter` function, but since your teacher insists on in-place processing, you can't use those. As much as I hate side-effects, here you are:

```
def remove_occurences(lst, val):
    # using filter in Python 3 (or ifilter in Python 2) requires O(1) memory;
    # it's not usually a good thing to update the object you are iterating,
    # but here we can be sure, nothing will go wrong: we can never overwrite
    # a value we must take before getting hold of its reference
    i = -1
    for i, value in enumerate(filter(lambda x: x != val, lst)):
        lst[i] = value
    # remove the tail
    del lst[i+1:len(lst)]
    return lst
```

Since we are dealing with imperative code, it's *imperative* to test it

```
from hypothesis import strategies as st
from hypothesis import given

@given(st.lists(elements=st.integers(0, 9), min_size=0, average_size=50, max_size=100),
       st.integers(0, 9))
def test(lst, val):                                                          
    assert remove_occurences(lst[:], val) == list(filter(lambda x: x != val, lst))
```

Calling `test()` will run several hundred random tests. The function has passed the tests. Now, since `del` on lists takes `O(n)` on average, we must make sure, that our tail-hack is a special case (which is most likely implementation dependent, but I guess the people behind CPython are clever enough to have optimised it long ago). Let's run some benchmarks:

```
In [45]: %timeit remove_occurences([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]*1, 3)
1.31 µs ± 30.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [46]: %timeit remove_occurences([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]*10, 3)
6.9 µs ± 243 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [47]: %timeit remove_occurences([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]*100, 3)
68.3 µs ± 5.82 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [48]: %timeit remove_occurences([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]*1000, 3)
733 µs ± 54 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [49]: %timeit remove_occurences([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]*10000, 3)
7.07 ms ± 295 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

The growth is clearly linear. That is actually expected, considering the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c) (see the comment)

```
...
    if (value == NULL) {
        /* delete slice */
        PyObject **garbage;
        size_t cur;
        Py_ssize_t i;
        int res;

        if (slicelength <= 0)
            return 0;

        if (step < 0) {
            stop = start + 1;
            start = stop + step*(slicelength - 1) - 1;
            step = -step;
        }

        garbage = (PyObject**)
            PyMem_MALLOC(slicelength*sizeof(PyObject*));
        if (!garbage) {
            PyErr_NoMemory();
            return -1;
        }

        /* drawing pictures might help understand these for
           loops. Basically, we memmove the parts of the
           list that are *not* part of the slice: step-1
           items for each item that is part of the slice,
           and then tail end of the list that was not
           covered by the slice */
...
```

Since we are deleting the tail, there is nothing to move, making it effectively a linear operation.

Comment: No, this isn't side effects. This is just an in place operation. There's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: in-place operations on arguments are side-effects, because they introduce the notion of state. Since this mutation is not enclosed within the function's scope, the state might as well be considered global.

Comment: So, you'd say a function like `random.shuffle` produces side effects?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yes, it does. Any operation leading to a race condition produces side-effects by definition. CPython's GIL just makes it easy to forget about that.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you're doing, but you're complicating it. There are two ways to do it.

**Option 1**
Return a new list. This can be done with a list comp or a loop.

```
def remove_all(lst, val):
    return [x for x in lst if x != val]
```

Or,

```
def remove_all_gen(lst, val):
    for i in lst:
        if i != val:
            yield i
```

```
print(list(remove_all([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2], 1)))
[2, 2, 3, 2]
```

Both these solution are linear.

---

**Option 2**
To modify the list in place, you can iterate in reverse, using `del`.

```
def remove_all(lst, val):
   for i in range(len(lst) - 1, -1, -1):
       if lst[i] == val:
          del lst[i]
```

```
l = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2]
remove_all(l, 1)

print(l)
[2, 2, 3, 2]
```

While this solution modifies the list in place, it is no longer linear (thanks to the comments) because `del` is a linear operation, requiring elements to be shifted.

As a matter of good practice, don't return anything from a function if you are performing an in-place mutation.

Comment: I cannot use option 1 because the assignment mentions not to create a new list. Option 2 is not linear time because the del command requires shifting the elements.

Comment: Note that the complexity of `del` for lists is O(n), so option 2 is not linear at all.

Comment: Also as an alternative `list(filterfalse(lambda x: x ==5, range(10)))` in **Python 3.x**

Comment: @MadhavNakar There's hardly anyway to delete repeatedly from a list in-place in linear time. Your best bet is a list comp.

Comment: @MadhavNakar Well, I'm sorry about your assignment not allowing you to do that. Guess that's too bad.

Comment: For example if a list of size n is filled with the same element, then in every loop it will call del, which is O(n). So if the loop runs n times, then it will be O(n*n).

Comment: @MadhavNakar No, if every list is filled with the same element, then `del` will always operate on the last element, being amortised constant in time, I believe.

Comment: I mean I was able to do it within the requirements (linear time and in place), but I was just interested in a different approach. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @MadhavNakar You have multiple loops, I don't think your answer is linear either, not anymore than `del`.

Comment: My guess is his teacher wants the program to be linear *(without caring about what Python does underneath the function call)*. If we consider the way Python deletes the values, I am not able to think of a way to update list in place.

Comment: Multiple loops do not necessarily mean non-linear time. The outer loop runs just a couple time because the inner loops make the front and back pointers reach the end.

Comment: @MadhavNakar So you're saying your two loops are linear, while a single loop + del is quadratic? Eh, I doubt that.

Comment: @MadhavNakar But that doesn't mean that execution of loop couple of times is linear. Nested loops are considered to fold the complexity (also by theory) by `N*M`. FYI, if there are couple of operations, then use `if` instead of `for`.

Comment: Two un-nested loops both of which are O(n) are still O(n). But in your implementation, where a O(n) loop contains a O(n) operation makes it O(n*n).

Comment: @MadhavNakar I am aware of how complexity is calculated. I was referring to the first loop which has an inner loop.

Comment: Long story short, it can not be done in plane linear time of `O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
def remove_all(l, item):
    try:
        while True:
            i = l.index(item)
            l.pop(i)
    except ValueError:
        return l
```

Comment: Both `index` and `pop` are not constant in time.

Comment: This is not linear

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ correctly points out that this is not linear. Using pop in the middle requires shifting.